# gdb in emacs, no such file or directory

Tags: macos, emacs, gdb, osx-mavericks

Trying to use gdb in emacs, but every time I run it, I get the message No such file or directory, gdb. My research initially led me to understand that it was not installed, so I have now installed a copy of gdb that seemed to go ok, but it seems that it is not being used by emacs.

I am running Emacs version 24.3 (9.0) on mac OSX Mavericks, and as far as I am aware I have gdb 7.6 installed.

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Kind regards

Rob

Answer (score 1):

Maybe emacs isn't picking up the right path, try this

1. Switch to *scratch* buffer
2. Then type `C-u M-: (getenv "PATH") RET`

The above will print the value of `PATH` in the buffer, check if it has the path to `gdb`

Answer (score 1):

I run into the similar problem. I'm using Yosemite. I install gdb using macports `port install gdb` and the gdb is installed as `ggdb` instead of `gdb` under `/opt/local/bin/ggdb`.

The way I workaround the problem is the following:

1. I first create an symbolic soft link under my `$HOME/bin` directory (i.e. `/Users/zeyuan/bin`): `ln -s /opt/local/bin/ggdb $HOME/bin/gdb`
2. Then I add the following chunk under emacs `init.el`:

   `(setenv "PATH" "/Users/zeyuan/bin:$PATH" t)
   (add-to-list 'exec-path "/Users/zeyuan/bin")`

With these two steps, I can invoke `gdb` through emacs. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same situation and found a solution at http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.help/100522

Adding below code to my .emacs file has solved the problem for me

```
    (add-to-list 'load-path "~/elisp")
    (require 'exec-path-from-shell)

    (when (memq window-system '(mac ns))
    (exec-path-from-shell-initialize))
```

Hope that will help